# Noflo-ui no runtime installed

Tags: noflo

I followed the instructions outlined online at https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui to setup the Noflo-ui locally on my device. The build goes fine.

However, when I access the webpage I don't see any local runtime registered.

Do I have to install a runtime manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to setup a local runtime manually. Please take a look at the following article for instructions on how to setup a NoFlo runtime with Flowhub:

http://docs.flowhub.io/article/84-getting-started-node-js

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've got no problem setting up and running the noflo-nodejs server instance locally. The problem I'm having is that I want to run the UI itself locally, as in download the Git repo, build it and run it physically on the device. Once that works, I want to connect the local nodejs instance to noflo. So any thoughts on getting the UI working?